# Why is this form of writing the six antisymmetric gamma matrices correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I encountered the following expression in Ashok Das' QFT Lectures:
$$\sigma_{\mu \nu } =\frac{i}{2}[\gamma ^\mu,\gamma^\nu]=i(\eta ^{\mu \nu}-\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu)=-i(\eta ^{\mu \nu}-\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu).$$

I understand why the expression with $+i$ is correct, but I have no idea how we go from that expression to the one with $-i$. I tried something like changing the indexes and using the fact that the metric is symmetric, but that doesn't help me with the negative sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we know that the gamma matrices obey the Clifford algebra $$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$

Because of that we have

$$i(\eta^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)=i\left[\eta^{\mu\nu}-(2\eta^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)\right]=i(-\eta^{\mu\nu}+\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)=-i(\eta^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)$$